# Calculate Bitmap tile height so last item not cropped

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-custom-view

The problem is to create tile background which will stretch by X axis in such a way that last element won't be cropped.

**What I want** (calculate height of each "dot" image so last tile won't be cropped):
[image]

**What I have** (see last element is cropped):

[image]

There should be a way to create custom class extending `ImageView` or `Bitmap` and implement that calculation manually. But I can't really get any information about how to do that properly.

bg_dots.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_dot"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

and that how its used:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_dots" />
```

---

**EDIT :**

Thanks to @paulina_glab's article and information provided I've been able to create custom view which draws repeating tile drawable. BUT there's still problem with calculation actual width\height of bitmap to fit screen height.

Calculation I do involves float-to-int round and that brings delta. Bitmap requires integers as width and height but calculation shows that it should be float value to fit screen exactly.

Here's what I came with:

```
public class DotsView extends View {
private Rect rect;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private BitmapDrawable mDrawable;

private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;
private int calculatedHeight;
private int calculatedWidth;

public DotsView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public DotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public DotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    Resources res = getResources();

    //get window specs
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);


    //get bitmap from resource image
    mBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_dot);

    //define width and height of custom view after all modifications
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    //calculate proportion of height\width so the last element wont be cropped
    calculatedHeight = calculateHeight();
    calculatedWidth = calculateWidth();
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight, false);

    //create drawable from customized bitmap
    mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, mBitmap);
    //set it to be repeating tile
    mDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

    //define borders of drawable to de drawn in
    rect = new Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, calculatedHeight);
    mDrawable.setBounds(rect);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(screenWidth, calculatedHeight);
    setMeasuredDimension(screenWidth, calculatedHeight);
}

private int calculateWidth(){
    /*such calculation brings delta from conversion float to int. This delta doesn't let to draw
    * exactly 25 dots. Any workarounds? */
    return (int)(mBitmap.getWidth() / ((float)(mBitmap.getWidth() * 25) / screenWidth)); //draw around 25 dots
}

private int calculateHeight(){
    return (int)(screenHeight * 0.07); //make it around 7 percents of screen
}
}
```

Please look at `calculateWidth()` method.

What it looks like (due to delta there's still cropped dot): 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do custom drawing within the Android system, you should just make use of the Android framework and things like measuring and layouting will be a lot easier.

```
return (int)(screenHeight * 0.07); //make it around 7 percents of screen
```

If you "guess" the height in `onMeasure` you're not really measuring the view. You want 25 dots, distributed along the width of the view, so this is what you should do.

1. Get rid of `WindowManager`, `Display`, etc. Android now has split screen mode, there's soft navigation bars...the screen size does not really matter.
2. Use the Android framework.

It's always the same process: measure, layout, draw.

### Measuring

You're in `onMeasure`, so *measure*. `widthMeasureSpec` contains the information you need—in this case the available width. Read it with `MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)`.

Now you want 25 dots along this width and have a height respectively...so all you need to do is divide `width / 25` and you'll know how tall your view should be.

Finish measuing by telling the framework how tall you want to be!

```
setMeasuredDimension(availableWidth, neededHeight);
```

### Layouting

If something changed..whatever the reason...here we get the final size of the view. Adapt your drawable, scale your image, calculate bounds...

Just try not to do too complex work, since this might get called *a lot*.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    // called after measuring. here we know the actual size of our view

    // assuming it's a square, else do some Math.min to get a valid size
    int size = bottom - top;

    // set the size for the drawable, maybe scale up / down, maybe center...
    mDrawable.setBounds(left, top, left + size, top + size);
}
```

### Drawing

You can do full custom drawing by just creating some `Paint` and do some `drawCircle(...)` on the canvas, or you can just use some `Drawable`. There are endless possibilities on how to draw a dot.

You want it 25 times so add a loop and make sure to move it along the x axis. Now you're set!

---

Since this is a lot to grasp, here's a simple example, with a basic drawable. I also wrote an article about [view basics](http://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/07/10/custom-views.html) with some more information about measuring and layouting. Try to see how it works (I myself love playing with the layout preview in Android Studio to test my views!). Once you understand how to measure and layout your view all that's left is to properly scale your bitmap.

```
public class DotsView extends View {
    private static final int NUM_DOTS = 25;

    private Drawable mDrawable;

    public DotsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mDrawable = new DotDrawable();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // measure where you're supposed to measure: in onMeasure

        // get all of the width
        // this will work with match_parent, as well as with a width of 32dp
        int availableWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        // NUM_DOTS == 25, or whatever, use a constant or read into attributes
        int neededHeight = (int) (availableWidth / (float) NUM_DOTS);

        // apply the measure dimension to the view
        setMeasuredDimension(availableWidth, neededHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        // called after measuring. here we know the actual size of our view

        // assuming it's a square, else do some Math.min to get a valid size
        int size = bottom - top;

        // set the size for the drawable, maybe scale up / down, maybe center...
        mDrawable.setBounds(left, top, left + size, top + size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // get the width of this view and calculate the width used per dot
        float widthPerDot = getWidth() / (float) NUM_DOTS;

        // draw every single dot where it belongs.
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DOTS; i++) {
            // just redraw the same drawable and move it along the x axis
            mDrawable.getBounds().offsetTo((int) ((i * widthPerDot)), 0);

            // finally just draw the dot
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
    public class DotDrawable extends android.graphics.drawable.Drawable {

        Paint mPaint;

        DotDrawable() {
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            Rect bounds = getBounds();
            canvas.drawCircle(bounds.centerX(), bounds.centerY(), Math.min(bounds.width(), bounds.height()) / 2, mPaint);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... That's some amazing explanation! Thanks a lot for giving such a detailed information. Works like a charm.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to do the same with `BitmapDrawable` instead of simple `Drawable`? Tried it and it draws only one dot taken from resources. 
Inside `init()`: `Bitmap mBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_dot);
mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBitmap);`

Comment: @AnZ A bitmap drawable is also a `Drawable`. Don't forget looping or adjusting the bounds. And there is always the option to just do `canvas.drawBitmap` yourself, which I myself prefer for having full control.

Comment: That's it! I've scaled bitmap to `bounds.width()` and `bounds.height()` and after that`canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, bounds.left, bounds.top,mPaint)` did all the magic. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the way to do what you want via `bitmap`/`xml`, but (as you thought) I can suggest creating custom [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class.

[View.onDraw()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method let you to define *custom drawing process* and in

[View.onSizeChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) you can *calculate proper count/height of dots*.

You can draw ***single dot*** using [Drawable.draw()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)).

Than you get *a custom wiget*, which you'll be able to put inside some layout container (like e.g. `TextView`, not as `android:background`).

---

I wrote an [article about drawing custom views](http://gogreenyellow.com/articles/custom-view-awesome-pie-chart) - a case described there is more complex, but you can see there usage of each method I mentioned above. For example, you can skip paragraphs about `Path`s or attributes.

And this is an [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). That might also be useful for you, but it's very general.

Comment: @AnZ Thanks :) Custom Views are one of my favorite part of Android development. Let know if you stuck somewhere.